# Best method to retry to submit a form if a network error occurs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

It may happen that a HTML form can be loaded, but cannot be submitted due to a network error (in context of a mobile application). The browser will show an error in this case. Is there a method to hide this error to the user and keep retrying to submit the form?

Comment: prob with ajax. Provide more information.

Comment: A possible solution: The submit button does not submit the form, but starts periodically running AJAX calls to transfer the form data until it is really accepted by the server and then redirects.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is using regular submission then you have no control of qhat happens after the user clicks submit. The only way you can keep retrying is by Ajax because you get a response back to your JS code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onclick` event of `<input type="button" />` to trigger a function that sends an AJAX request repeatedly until a status of `200` (OK) is received, then redirect the user to the next page. For better or worse, if the browser displays a message in regards to the network connection, that is beyond the control of javascript, HTML, and PHP.